# Sql daily comparison by month

Tags: sql, date, comparison

I am writing a report for work which requires that I compare the amount of students dropped on a daily basis, what I mean is the report needs to show that on today the 5th of august X amounts of students dropped from the 1st to the 5th compared to X amount which dropped within the 1st to the 5th of July and so on for each Month of the year. Can anyone please help me by providing me with a query which I can use to have that info? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You want to compare the first number of days from a month.  The following query gives you an example:

```
select yr, mon, count(*)
from (select extract(year from date) as yr, extract(month from date) as mon,
             extract(day from date) as day
      from t
     ) t
where day <= extract(day from now())
group by yr, mon
```

However, the exact syntax may depend on your database.  For instance, the current date may be now(), getdate(), system_date or something else.  Some databases don't support the extract, but most have a way to get the month and day of month.